# Proving that $A =A(B-I)$ and $B =B(A-I)$ implies $ A^2=2A$ and $B^2=2B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrices, which satisfy $A=A(B-I)$ and $B=B(A-I)$. I want to prove that $A^2 = 2A$ and $B^2 = 2B$.

Here is my try:
I express each equation as
$A(B-2I)=0$. I want to use determinants to prove that $A$ is invertible. If I can do this, then I can multiply by $A^{-1}$ and get the equation $A=2I$. Then I can multiply again by $A$ to get the desired equation. But I didn’t succeed in proving that $\det(A)$ is not equal to $0$. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hint: isolate the cross-terms and do some clever left-multiply. For example, $A = AB - A$, so...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: But I don’t know if A is invertible

Answer (score 2):

We know that $A=A(B-I)$ ,so $2A=AB$,then left-multiply $B$,we get $2BA=BAB$.We can also know that $2B=BA$ because of $A=A(B−I)$.So $BAB=(BA)B=2B^{2}=2BA$ ,then$B^{2}=BA=2B$.

We can get$A^{2}=2A$ in the same way.

Comment: Thank you  I didn’t think about it like that.